# XSLT: abbreviation of reocurring xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

in an XSL transformation, I've got a rather lengthy XPath (an union of about 20 different nodes). Because this path is needed frequently, an abbreviation of it would be nice.

The abbreviation must be made in a way that it does evaluate in the current context, so using a global variable or something will not work.

Target version is XSLT 1.0 with EXSLT extensions.

Thanks,
Jost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't have a global variable then a [function](http://www.exslt.org/func/elements/function/index.html) may be the solution.

Comment: To be fair, if you didn't have EXSLT, this wouldn't be possible, so it's not that obvious.

Comment: Yeah, but I am using functions all the time... my first idea here was to define an entity, but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use entities to provide an abbreviation of the lengthy XPath**.

XSLT is an XML file, so XML entities can be used anywhere within the XSLT.  The entities will be expanded and resolved as the XSLT is parsed.

Something that you can do with entities that you cannot do with a global XSLT variable is to use the entity within XPath and match expressions.

For instance, you could create an entity for your long XPath statement and re-use it in multiple locations like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY lengthyXPath "elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6 | elem7 | elem8 | elem9 | elem10 | elem11 | elem12 | elem13 | elem14 | elem15 | elem16 | elem17 | elem18 | elem19 | elem20">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>     
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
            <xsl:comment>mached foo child elements from: &lengthyXPath;</xsl:comment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="&lengthyXPath;"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bar">
            <xsl:comment>mached bar child elements from: &lengthyXPath;</xsl:comment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="&lengthyXPath;"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="baz">
            <xsl:comment>mached baz child elements from: &lengthyXPath;</xsl:comment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="&lengthyXPath;"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="&lengthyXPath;">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML:

```
 <doc>
    <foo>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem1>1</elem1>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem3>3</elem3>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem5>5</elem5>
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem7>7</elem7>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem9>9</elem9>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem10>10</elem10>
    </bar>
    <baz>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem11>11</elem11>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem13>13</elem13>
        <elem>no match</elem>
        <elem15>15</elem15>
    </baz>
</doc>
```

Produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output><!--mached foo child elements from: elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6 | elem7 | elem8 | elem9 | elem10 | elem11 | elem12 | elem13 | elem14 | elem15 | elem16 | elem17 | elem18 | elem19 | elem20--><elem1>1</elem1>
   <elem3>3</elem3>
   <elem5>5</elem5>
   <!--mached bar child elements from: elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6 | elem7 | elem8 | elem9 | elem10 | elem11 | elem12 | elem13 | elem14 | elem15 | elem16 | elem17 | elem18 | elem19 | elem20--><elem7>7</elem7>
   <elem9>9</elem9>
   <elem10>10</elem10>
   <!--mached baz child elements from: elem1 | elem2 | elem3 | elem4 | elem5 | elem6 | elem7 | elem8 | elem9 | elem10 | elem11 | elem12 | elem13 | elem14 | elem15 | elem16 | elem17 | elem18 | elem19 | elem20--><elem11>11</elem11>
   <elem13>13</elem13>
   <elem15>15</elem15>
</output>
```